# YOLOv3-tiny and DarkNet - 2 classes but classifies only 1

Tags: python, opencv, yolo, darknet

I want to create a net with yolov3-tiny that detects cars and motorcycles, so I have created my own dataset with 100 car images and 100 motorcycles images. In the annotation files the labels are correct (0 to cars and 1 to motorcycles). Since I have 2 classes, I have modified the yolov3-tiny.cfg as setting the classes to 2 and the filters to (classes+5)*3 = 21. I also modified batch to 24 and subdivisions to 8. Here is the complete cfg file (./custom/car_moto-yolov3-tiny.cfg):

```
[net]
# Testing
batch=24
subdivisions=8
# Training
# batch=64
# subdivisions=2
width=416
height=416
channels=3
momentum=0.9
decay=0.0005
angle=0
saturation = 1.5
exposure = 1.5
hue=.1

learning_rate=0.001
burn_in=1000
max_batches = 5000
policy=steps
steps=400000,450000
scales=.1,.1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=16
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=32
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=64
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=2

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[maxpool]
size=2
stride=1

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=1024
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

###########

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=512
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=21
activation=linear



[yolo]
mask = 3,4,5
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=2
num=6
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1

[route]
layers = -4

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=128
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[upsample]
stride=2

[route]
layers = -1, 8

[convolutional]
batch_normalize=1
filters=256
size=3
stride=1
pad=1
activation=leaky

[convolutional]
size=1
stride=1
pad=1
filters=21
activation=linear

[yolo]
mask = 0,1,2
anchors = 10,14,  23,27,  37,58,  81,82,  135,169,  344,319
classes=2
num=6
jitter=.3
ignore_thresh = .7
truth_thresh = 1
random=1
```

Then I have created the .names file (./data/custom_cfg.names) with:

```
cars
motorcylcles
```

Created the train.txt, test.txt and the the obj.data (./custom/obj.data) with:

```
classes= 2
train  = data/train.txt
valid  = data/test.txt
names = data/custom_cfg.names
backup = yolov3-tiny_2classes
```

Finally, I have started the training by using the darknet53.conv.74 model by executing the command

```
darknet detector train custom/obj.data custom/car_moto-yolov3-tiny.cfg darknet53.conv.74.
```

Here is a sample output of the training process:

```
5998: 0.619981, 0.483621 avg loss, 0.001000 rate, 0.499771 seconds, 143952 images, 0.011460 hours left
Loaded: 0.000028 seconds
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.828822), count: 3, class_loss = 0.617392, iou_loss = 0.131867, total_loss = 0.749259 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000005, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000005 
 total_bbox = 172619, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 % 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.762853), count: 3, class_loss = 1.025908, iou_loss = 0.332650, total_loss = 1.358558 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000002, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000002 
 total_bbox = 172622, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 % 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.841586), count: 3, class_loss = 0.431826, iou_loss = 0.156079, total_loss = 0.587906 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000002, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000002 
 total_bbox = 172625, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 % 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.743486), count: 3, class_loss = 0.947532, iou_loss = 0.385455, total_loss = 1.332986
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000001, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000001
 total_bbox = 172628, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 % 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.798283), count: 3, class_loss = 0.519976, iou_loss = 0.205342, total_loss = 0.725317 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000001, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000001 
 total_bbox = 172631, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 % 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.843649), count: 3, class_loss = 0.362844, iou_loss = 0.099908, total_loss = 0.462752 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000002, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000002 
 total_bbox = 172634, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 % 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.757608), count: 4, class_loss = 0.757355, iou_loss = 0.273935, total_loss = 1.031290 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000002, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000002 
 total_bbox = 172638, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 % 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 16 Avg (IOU: 0.775621), count: 3, class_loss = 0.883560, iou_loss = 0.192446, total_loss = 1.076006 
v3 (mse loss, Normalizer: (iou: 0.75, obj: 1.00, cls: 1.00) Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), count: 1, class_loss = 0.000000, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000000 
 total_bbox = 172641, rewritten_bbox = 0.000000 %
```

And that's the thing. I always got Region 23 Avg (IOU: 0.000000), class_loss = 0.000000, iou_loss = 0.000000, total_loss = 0.000000 or something very close to this. Then, when I put the network to run, it classifies only one class, the "cars". Even the motorcycles are classified as cars.
Someone can help with this?

Here are some input images examples:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: You may have made a mistake while labelling data.
Have you labeled 'cars' as label 0 and 'motorcycles' as label 1 in the annotation files?

Comment: Yes, I did. I've edited the question and added this detail. Thanks.

Comment: can you explain the entries of the "v3" starting lines during training? I think it is interesting that there's always one line with count:3-4 and followed ny a line with count:1. If count:1 is the motorcycle, it looks imbalanced. Can you show some typical images?

Comment: I don't know exactly what these output lines means (I knew YOLO and DarkNet from about 2 weeks ago), but yes, those lines with 1 correspond to the motorcycles. If it's unbalanced, what should I do? I've editeed the post and added some input images examples.

Answer (score 0):

Just needed to adjust some parameters in the .cfg file and it worked.